# Simple way to pass variables to CFLAGS in a make file

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile which looks like below. I use `ifeq` to add variables to compiler flags.

```
ABC=1
XYZ=1

ifeq ($(ABC),1)
CFLAGS+= -DABC
endif

ifeq ($(XYZ),1)
CFLAGS+= -DXYZ
endif

...
```

Is there a cleaner way to add all variables to CFLAGS instead of using ifeq for all?

Comment: How do you feel about `foreach`?

Comment: If you wish to add different flags on different variables that seems quite a good way to go.

Comment: how do you use foreach on above case? The way ABC and XYZ are defined should not change

Comment: Do your `-D` values always correspond to the variable name, e.g. when a variable is named `ABC` you want to add `-DABC` or is it possible to set different symbol?

Comment: yes, always. We have some many such variables defined in separate inc file and hence like to have them automatically add -D for each of them

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a cleaner way to add all variables to `CFLAGS` instead of using `ifeq` for all?

You can use [computed variable names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html) to avoid those verbose `ifeq` blocks:

```
ABC=1
XYZ=1

cflags.abc.1 := -DABC
cflags.xyz.1 := -DXYZ

CFLAGS += cflags.abc.${ABC} cflags.xyz.${XYZ}
```

It uses the fact that unset variables expand to empty strings in GNU make.

Comment: thanks but it does not look any cleaner to me. I would NOT like to use ABC or XYZ again once they are defined

Comment: @Rahul Cannot understand you.